# Cannot mirror my laptop (windows 10) to Panasonic Smart Viera TV TX-32FS500B

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, tv, mirroring, smart-tv

What I can do is:

- connect TV and laptop to internet wifi

I can see the TV to connect on my laptop as it appears in the following image link:

[Add a Device (dialogue message)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEZHn.png)

But it displays "Couldn't connect" message

I have updated to the latest firmware on my smart tv and drivers (Wifi and network) on my windows 10 laptop.

Have check that my laptop supports miracast

Have Restarted both TV and Laptop

Comment: I have now found out that mirroring feature for my TV is only compatible with Android devices

Comment: Welcome to Super User, and kudos for solving your problem.  Consider posting an answer with what you learned, which could help other users who encounter the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Mirroring feature for Panasonic 32FS500B TV is only compatible with Android devices. Source Panasonic customer services

Comment: I doubt that's true. Customer services sometimes give spurious answers. Miracast does not any Android-only APIs or protocols as far as I'm aware. Maybe Panasonic makes their own Android app but other devices might come with the functionality or have it available by third-party apps. Did you have Bluetooth turned on? Miracast uses Bluetooth for discovery but uses Wi-Fi for actually streaming the data. I'm using a different Panasonic Viera and I have conntect with my Android phone and my Windows 10 laptop, though the laptop only works sometimes.